# Chrome Incorrectly Rending CSS Content Counters

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-counter

**Problem:**

I was looking to replace the browser's default list-style-type with my own custom `::before` pseudo-element. I chose this over the `::marker` because of some of the styling limitations the `::marker` has.

The HTML code I have has "type" attributes that change what kind of character should appear before the `li`.

**HTML code:**

```
<ol type="decimal">
  <li>First ordered item</li>
  <li>Second ordered item
    <ol type="a">
      <li>First ordered item</li>
      <li>Second ordered item
        <ol type="A">
          <li>First ordered item</li>
          <li>Second ordered item</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    </ol>
  </li>  
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

This is the CSS I made, using the `counter` to style it:

```
ol {
    /*list-style-type: none*/
    counter-reset: li;
}

ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: li;
    content: counter(li) ". ";
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: red;
}

ol[type="decimal"] > li:before {
    content: counter(li, decimal) ". ";
}

ol[type="a" s] > li:before {
    content: counter(li, lower-alpha) ". ";
}

ol[type="A" s] > li:before {
    content: counter(li, upper-alpha) ". ";
}
```

The "s" after `type="a"` and `type="A"` means case-sensitive matches. https://caniuse.com/css-case-insensitive

**Firefox vs Chrome:**

Looking at the rendered, **red characters**:

Firefox renders these lists correctly, with the first two being numbers, and the second two  being lowercase letters and the last two being uppercase letters.

Chrome renders them incorrectly, with everything being numbers.

[image]

Is this an issue with my code/browser support, or is this a bug in Google Chrome?

```css
ol {
    /*list-style-type: none*/
    counter-reset: li;
}

ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: li;
    content: counter(li) ". ";
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: red;
}

ol[type="decimal"] > li:before {
    content: counter(li, decimal) ". ";
}

ol[type="a" s] > li:before {
    content: counter(li, lower-alpha) ". ";
}

ol[type="A" s] > li:before {
    content: counter(li, upper-alpha) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol type="decimal">
  <li>First ordered item</li>
  <li>Second ordered item
    <ol type="a">
      <li>First ordered item</li>
      <li>Second ordered item
        <ol type="A">
          <li>First ordered item</li>
          <li>Second ordered item</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    </ol>
  </li>  
</ol>
```

Thank you.

Comment: According to caniuse Chrome does not support the case sensitive modifier.The link you gave goes to the case-insensitive modifier, which Chrome does support it seems.

Comment: Gah! That would do it. Did you want to put that as an answer so I can give you points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to caniuse Chrome does not support the case sensitive modifier at the moment (Decmber 2022).

The link you gave goes to the case-**insensitive** modifier, which Chrome does support it seems.

So it's an issue with browser support rather than a bug as such or an issue with your code